# How to get HTML element height in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP code which produces a HTML `table` like:

I want to cut this table somewhere when the PDF page length I'm producing is reached.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>column two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>here have more text<br>set more text<br>get this tr tag Height</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>this tr's height is not same<br>like column three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get height for each `tr` tags.
How to do this question with javascript?

In addition, if this `table` is writen using PHP...
How to solve this question?

Comment: elements have properties, including things like `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` - or methods like `getBoundingClientRect` - these would be useful in javascript to get what you need - you wont have any luck with getting such information in PHP, unless your page sends such data in an AJAX request

Comment: There is no JS code... Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'll try to use these three properties.

Comment: actually, this code just a example. I have a program. this program have a long table tag, I need to let table tag split. And I have an idea. I give a number to limit table height, and use javascript to get each tr's height, and Cumulative each heigh number, if it is over the table height limit , I'll add ＜／table>＜table border="1" class="class1"> to split table.

Comment: So you want to know each `tr` height on the PHP side, in your loop that produces the table right?

Comment: I had try it. And I know to use offsetHeight to get element's height. But how to get each height number. and how to insert ＜／table>＜table border="1" class="class1"> to split this table .

Comment: HTML is not rendered yet, on PHP side. So you can't know it.

Comment: Yes! By the way, I know to use offsetHeight to get height in javascript. But , how to get each tr height in PHP?

Comment: Hey! Maybe you could "estimate" the height of each `td` on PHP side... By counting the character amount. You know the `line-height`($lh) and `td` widths($tw)? `substr()` the `td` content($tc) by spaces and you'll have the word count($wc). There is an estimate possible to do about word *average char length* ($wacv) * word count($wc) = line count($lc) -> td height! ($tdh)  ----> `(($wacv*$wc)/$tw)*&lh = $tdh` This would be a way to approach the PHP task, since you create a PDF on PHP side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By **counting the character amount for each `td` of a row** and a calculation to estimate line amount.

You can have the character count.
Using PHP `explode()` on the `td` content by spaces, you'll have the word count.

An estimate can be used... About word average char length to obtain the line count.
I attempted a calcuation about it (`$acpw` below)... But you could use a constant instead.

So this, multiplied by the known CSS line height, you know this `td` height.

```
(($acpw*$wc)/$tw)*&lh = $tdh
```

This would be a way to approach the PHP task, since you create a PDF on PHP side.  *(seen in comments)*
**This is just a starter****.**.. Since you provided no code.
;)

---

```
<?php

// Declare a result array 
$row_height=[];

// Average char per word === Estimated constant.
$acpw = 8;

// Td width, should be known
$tw = 140; // in px.

// Line-height, should be known
&lh = 16; // in px.

// while parsing each th in a row
$i=0;
while($td_content=$something){
  $ca = strlen($td_content['string'])
  // word count
  $wc = $td_content['string'].explode(" ");

  // Average Char count per word calculation attemp, can be commented to use the constant
  $acpw = $ca/$wc;

  // The formula!
  $tdh = (($acpw  * $wc)/$tw)*$lh;

  // Save in array
  $row_height[$i] = $tdh;
  $i++;
}

// Now you know the row height of this row...
$max = max($row_height);

// You have to determine if there is enought space for the next loop.
if($space_left>$max+$footer){
  $space_left = $page_length-$max;

// Else split the table!
}else{
  echo"</table><table>";
}



// There is a couple strings to attach in this code...
?>
```

*And this is not tested.*

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged Jquery, so I suppose if it is the case of Jquery, use $('tr').innerHeight() or $('tr').outerHeight()

Comment: actually, this code just a example.
I have a program.
this program have a long table tag,
I need to let table tag split.
And I have an idea.

I give a number to limit table height,
and use javascript to get each tr's height,
and Cumulative each heigh number,
if it is over the table height limit ,
I'll add ＜／table>＜table border="1" class="class1"> to split table.

Comment: I had try it. And I know to use offsetHeight to get element's height. But how to get each height number. and how to insert ＜／table>＜table border="1" class="class1"> to split this table .

Comment: @卓琮偉 you're complicating things, If it's just the problem of paging your long table, you should consider specifying the ***number of rows per table*** instead of fixing your table height. That's way you can split your table easily without having to calculate any height.

Comment: why I need to calculate height? Because, my program have form to fill. my customer all docter. they need to fill in patient's medical records information,  you know that will have a long table, And I need to convert it to PDF. So that height is not stable. That's why I need to set a number to limit table height.(a PDF page height limit.)

Comment: I also agreed with @KingKing that you are complicating things. But if you want to keep your approach then there is 1 solution: defining all rows which are the "cutting-points" (by sum up the heights and compare to the page height). Then add a class for instance"cut-here" to these rows. (suppose you have table of 3 pages then you have 3 cutting-points). After that, use jquery and the "cut-here" class to rebuild 3 tables from the original and replace the original.